# Error calling a public constructor in a TC ran using jacoco:cover

Tags: unit-testing, junit, playframework-2.0, code-coverage, jacoco

When I am running my play code with jacoco:cover, the test cases execution are failing when the constructor is called.

Simply put: My test code is like

```
@Test
public void ValidSessionIdFindBySessionId() throws Exception 
{
    RightnowAccount rightnowAccount = new RightnowAccount("Login", "Password", 123, "SessionId");
}
```

My Class and the constructor:

```
public class RightnowAccount extends Model
{
    private static final Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(RightnowAccount.class);
    @Id
    public String login;
    public String password;
    public int accountId;
    String sessionId;
    Timestamp createdTimeStamp;
    Timestamp updatedTimeStamp;

    public RightnowAccount (String login)
    {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public RightnowAccount (String login,String password,int accountId,String sessionId)
    {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }
}
```

When I am running the test code as play:cover, my test case fails with error:

```
[error] Test com.flipkart.rightnow.connection.RightnowAuthTest.ValidSessionIdFindBySessionId failed: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
[error] RightnowAccount.$jacocoInit()
[error] Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
[error]     at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:42)
```

Comment: Does the test have a Before or After method?

Comment: It seems that easymock tries to instrument class instrumented by jacoco. Are you using jacoco with agent (online instrumentation) or with offline instrumentation ?

Comment: Its an offline instrumentation